# How Expensive is Projecting onto a Polytope?

Tags: time-complexity, optimization, reference-request, computational-geometry, polygons

I have a problem where our *action set* is a polytope $\mathcal P\subset \mathbb R^d$ and an algorithm that involves projecting onto the action set. For example it says to select the Euclidean projection of $a \in \mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathcal P$.

I believe this can be done efficiently if $\mathcal P$ has a small number of facets. That means we can write $\mathcal P$ in half-space form $\{x \in \mathbb R^d: A x  \le b\}$ for some matrix $A$ with a small number $F$ of columns.

I would like to say "We can use the methods of [1] to project with $O(F)$ computational cost" but am having a hard time finding a clean reference.

In practice there are loads of ways to solve this quadratic programming problem, and in practice they do not get the exact projection; they just get an approximation and hopefully let us control the error by doing more work.

For example we  can use the $F$-many columns of the matrix $A$ as the constraint functions to run Lagrange multipliers. 
This turns the problem into an unconstrained optimisation problem where computing the function at each step requires adding up $F$-many things and so the computational cost is $O(F)$.

This method gives a sequence of points converging to the projection. Unfortunately these points probably won't be in the action set so we cannot stop at some finite stage and then select the approximate solutions as actions. We would like to stop at a finite stage and then project onto the action set but that gets us back to where we started!

Is there a way to get $O(F)$ complexity in such a way that our approximate solutions are in the action set? I am looking at self-concordant barriers  at the moment, but everything I can find is phrased in far more generality than needed for my problem and I cannot find a reference to the complexity.

**Edit:** Every self-concordant-barriers approach I can find also involves the Newton update and inverting the Hessian matrix. In general this costs at least $O(d^2)$.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2210394/14578, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra's_projection_algorithm, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292804/14578.